# How do I make all the finders on the model ignorecase?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model with several attributes, among them `title` and `artist`.

The case of `title` and `artist` should be ignored in all the Active Record finders.

Basically, if `title` or `artist` are present in the :conditions (or dynamically i.e. `find_all_by_artist`), then the `WHERE artist = :artist` should become `WHERE UPPER(artist) = UPPER(:artist)` or something along these lines.

Is there a way of doing it with Rails?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL database, searches are case **insensitive** by default. Read the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-sensitivity.html) for more details.

So `finder` call such as:

```
Album.find_all_by_artist("Nine Inch Nails").each do |album|
  p album.title
end
```

Is same as the call below:

```
Album.find_all_by_artist("NINE INCH NAILS").each do |album|
  p album.title
end
```

Both queries will print the same result:

```
# -> Pretty Hate Machine
# -> Broken
# -> ....
# -> The Slip
```